# Number of laptops in carry on baggage

Tags: uk, emirates, student-visas

I'll be using Emirates to get to the UK on a student visa from India via Dubai. How many laptops are we permitted to bring on board in cabin baggage? Are 2 laptops permitted in cabin baggage? My both laptops are used ones, they are not newly bought.

I checked on their website, and the weight of a carry-on  bag is listed as 7 kgs and only 1 piece. Does a laptop bag make it to cabin baggage weight? I therefore reasoned that I could have transported one laptop in a backpack and a second laptop in hand luggage. I would be very grateful if someone could provide some clarification on it for me.

Finally, if someone could give me the official email address for Emirates services, that would be really useful. I tried looking but was unsuccessful.

Comment: On Emirates in coach you can I or have a single item of hand luggage. If you have a backpack and a laptop bag then the backpack must be checked, so having a laptop in there wouldn’t be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

That should be fine.

There is no specific airline limits on the number of laptops. As long as you are not violating some other condition (weight, size, number, etc) you are good to go.

I typically have my laptop in my backpack and it's never been weighed or sized. Other cabin baggage (like roll-aboard) do get weighed occasionally and 7kg is not a whole lot so you would need to manage carefully what else you bring.

You will have to take them both out at security, so packing them for quick access may be useful. I always make sure that all by "take out" items are in the same bag. You can always reshuffle after security.

Comment: I've travelled in this exact situation on Emirates with multiple laptops. They did weight my cabin bag which was over the limit, but once I showed it was laptops they accepted it, as laptops can't be checked I think the best option for the staff is to be pragmatic and allow them on.  I wouldn't worry about it, especially if you aren't then filling your carry on luggage with other items.

Answer (score 0):

It depends as I have been asked to carry one laptop per reservation and had difficulties while travelling specially when I had connecting flights which got delayed.

Comment: This would be much more useful with more information. Who asked you? What airline? When? At what airport?